# How to use Google Maps in a fragment

Tags: android, maps, fragment

I'm trying to put this class in a fragment , how can I make it into a fragment class?

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }
```

I need these methods working in my fragment . But I'm not able to drive through the button

```
    public void onSearch(View view) {
        EditText location_tf = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFaddress);
        String location = location_tf.getText().toString();
        List<Address> addressList = null;
        if (location != null || !location.equals("")) {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
            try {
                addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                Address address = addressList.get(0);
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Marker"));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            }
    }
        public void onZoom(View view) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.Bzoomin) {
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());
        }
        if (view.getId() == R.id.Bzoomout) {
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomOut());
        }
    }

    public void changeType(View view) {
        if (mMap.getMapType() == GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL) {
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
        } else
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }
```

All these actions are connected to the layout through " onClick "

```
    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

what works for me is this

```
childFragmentManager.fragments[0] as SupportMapFragment?
```

Let me explain :  I have a fragment : Map Fragment and inside it there is an other fragmenr with the map so it is his only child. Be aware that i it is not the best practice but i works for now

```
class MapFragment : Fragment(), OnMapReadyCallback {

private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val rootView: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false)
    val mapFragment =
        childFragmentManager.fragments[0] as SupportMapFragment?
    mapFragment!!.getMapAsync(this)
    return rootView
}

override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap?) {
    mMap = googleMap!!
    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    val sydney = LatLng(-34.0, 151.0)
    mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"))
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney))
 }
}
```

my xml of my fragment is

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fragment Class should like this...

```
public MyMapFragment extends Fragment{

 private GoogleMap map;
    public GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;
    private Location myLocation;

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity()).addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
    }

@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstance) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstance);

        map = ((MapFragment) act.getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        map.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);
        map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
        map.setTrafficEnabled(true);
        map.setOnMarkerDragListener(dragListener);
        map.setOnMapLongClickListener(longClickListener);

    }

 @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null)
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

 private void showCurrentLocation(Location location) {
        if (map.getCameraPosition().zoom < MAP_ZOOM_LEVEl) {
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(
                    location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 12));
        }
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition(new LatLng(
                location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()),
                map.getCameraPosition().zoom, 45, 360);
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

    }

@Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
        }
        myLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (myLocation != null) {
            showCurrentLocation(myLocation);
            return;
        }
        if ("Check for GPS Status")
           Show the error if not enabled
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, locationRequest, new LocationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                        if (location == null)
                            return;
                        myLocation = location;
                        showCurrentLocation(location);
                    }
                });


    }

    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }

@Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();

        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getActivity()
                .getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        if (mapFragment != null)
            getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .remove(mapFragment).commit();
    }
}
```

Layout for that fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It worked for me, but how could I implement my onSeach methods onZoom and changeType ?

Answer (score 0):

In my project, Maps was implemented in the following way:

No meu projeto em implementei o Maps da seguindo maneira:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    MapFragment fragment = (MapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    fragment.getMapAsync(this);
} }
```